# Magic Square in Python Debugging

Tags: python-2.7, debugging, magic-square

Problem originally is in [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/ieeextreme-challenges/challenges/magic-square) link. I wrote a Python code but I got 64 points (total points is 100) and this indicates that my code has some missing points. I passed 11 of 16 test cases but 5 test cases have problematic for me. Could you say where my code has some missing points and how can I fix it?

```
import math

m = int(raw_input())
liste = []
y_liste = []
md = 0
ad = 0
sum = 0
sum2 = 0

for k in range(m):
    temp = str(raw_input())
    liste.append(temp)
    liste[k] = liste[k].split(" ")
    liste[k] = [int(i) for i in liste[k]]

for k in range(m):
    md += liste[k][k]
    ad += liste[k][m-k-1]



if md == ad:
    print 0
else:
    for k in range(m):
        for l in range(m):
            sum2 += liste[l][k]
            sum += liste[k][l]
        if sum2 != md and -(k+1) is not y_liste:
            y_liste.append(-(k+1))
        if sum != md and (k+1) is not y_liste:
            y_liste.append(k+1)
        sum2 = 0
        sum = 0

    if md != ad:
        y_liste.append(0)
    print len(y_liste)
    y_liste.sort()
    for i in y_liste:
        print i
```

**Problem Statement**

## Magic Square

Johnny designed a magic square (square of numbers with the same sum for all rows, columns and diagonals i.e. both the main diagonal - meaning the diagonal that leads from the top-left corner towards bottom-right corner - and the antidiagonal - meaning the diagonal that leads from top-right corner towards bottom-left corner). Write a program to test it.

**Task**
Write a program that will check if the given square is magic (i.e. has the same sum for all rows, columns and diagonals).

**Input**
First line: N , the size of the square (1 <= N <= 600).
Next N lines: The square, N space separated integers pre line, representing the entries per each row of the square.

**Output**
First line: M , the number of lines that do not sum up to the sum of the main diagonal (i.e. the one that contains the first element of the square). If the Square is magic, the program should output 0.
Next M lines: A sorted (in incremental order ) list of the lines that do not sum up to the sum of the main diagonal. The rows are numbered 1,2,…,N; the columns are numbered -1,-2,…,-N; and the antidiagonal is numbered zero.

Note: There is a newline character at the end of the last line of the output.
**Sample Input 1**
3
8 1 6
3 5 7
4 9 2

**Sample Output 1**
0

**Sample Input 2**
4
16 3 2 13
5 10 11 8
6 9 7 12
4 15 14 1

**Sample Output 2**
3
-2
-1
0

**Explanation of Sample Output 2**
The input square looks as follows:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyMgc.png
(Sorry for link but I cannot add image due to reputation)

The square has 4 rows (labeled from 1 to 4 in orange) and 4 columns (labeled from -1 to -4 in green) as depicted in the image above. The main diagonal and antidiagonal of the square are highlighted in red and blue respectively.

The main diagonal has sum = 16 + 10 + 7 +1 = 34.
The antidiagonal has sum = 13 + 11 + 9 + 4 = 37. This is different to the sum of the main diagonal so value 0 corresponding to the antidiagonal should be reported.
Row 1 has sum = 16 + 3 + 2 + 13 = 34.
Row 2 has sum = 5 + 10 + 11 + 8 = 34.
Row 3 has sum = 6 + 9 + 7 + 12 = 34.
Row 4 has sum = 4 + 15 + 14 + 1 = 34.
Column -1 has sum = 16 + 5 + 6 + 4 = 31. This is different to the sum of the main diagonal so value -1 should be reported.
Column -2 has sum = 3 + 10 + 9 + 15 = 37. This is different to the sum of the main diagonal so value -2 should be reported.
Column -3 has sum = 2 + 11 + 7 + 14 = 34.
Column -4 has sum = 13 + 8 + 12 + 1 = 34.
Based on the above, there are 3 lines that do not sum up to the sum of the elements of the main diagonal. Since they should be sorted in incremental order, the output should be:
3
-2
-1
0

Comment: Can you rephrase your question so that you list just the essence, but in particular, the five test cases that are problematic for you? (I.e., what are the test cases, and what output do you get/what parts does your program fail to get correct (for example, does it fail to get the sum across the diagonal correct?).

Comment: I can't readily find in your description whether these magic squares allow for multiple uses of the same number (usually, it's only one number per square); or whether the numbers need to be sequential (1, 2, 3 ...); or whether the numbers start at 1, 0 or anywhere?

Comment: Only first 2 test cases are given and there is no problem is over there. The other 14 test cases are not seen. Program fill and test automatically for the other test cases and it says which tests are passed or not passed.

Comment: @Evert I don't understand what did you said in second comment but If I understand, I'll explain little bit. First output of program  (I'm talking about after else statement) refers that legth of sequence (this is 3 in example) the other prints that refers the reported rows/column.(-2, -1) But there is also one more thing. The output be in incremental order after the length of sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your explanation doesn't discuss this clause which is a potential source of error:

```
if md == ad:
    print 0
else:
```

It says that if the main diagonal and antidiagonal add up to the same value, print just a 0 (no bad lines) indicating the magic square is valid (distinct from reporting a 0 in the list of bad lines).  Consider this valid magic square:

```
 9  6  3 16
 4 15 10  5
14  1  8 11
 7 12 13  2
```

If I swap 13 and 11, the diagonals still equal each other but the square is invalid.  So the above code doesn't appear to be correct.  In the `else` clause for the above `if` statement, you test:

```
if md != ad:
    y_liste.append(0)
```

a fact you already know to be true from the previous/outer test so your code seems to be out of agreement with itself.